# Resetting ajax mock calls count in Jest tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jasmine, jestjs

I have test structure represented below, my code uses ajax calls so I'm mocking as represented in the [Jest tutorial](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/tutorial/__tests__/fetchCurrentUser-test.js):

```
describe('it behavior', function() {
  it('is as it is', function() {
    jQuery.ajax.mock.calls[0][0].success({
      data: []
    });
    ...
  });
  it('is is not as it was', function() {
    jQuery.ajax.mock.calls[1][0].success({
      data: [1, 2, 3]
    });
    ...
  });
});
```

What bothers me most is this `jQuery.ajax.mock.calls[X][0]` in every case, mostly because I made typos or forget to increment call number in mock.

Is it possible to reset mock call count in `afterEach` callback or some pattern for test organisation in that case? Preferably without any extra test dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
describe('something', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    jQuery.ajax = jest.genMockFunction()
  })

  it('does something', function() {
    // do something
  })
}
```